# If statement true but not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

The following piece of javascript code does not what I expect. It's the code that is executed on succes of an ajax call but: although in some rounds of the $.each value1.html_id and redraw or reload are equal (and they are both strings) the if(){} code does never get executed. What am I missing here?

The console.log() outside the if statements gets executed and I can see that the values are the same, but the code in the {} of the if never gets executed

```
success: function(result) {
    activaTab(tab_id);
    $.each(tables, function(key, value1) {
        console.log(value1.html_id + redraw + reload)
        if (value1.html_id == redraw) {
            console.log('works');
            value1.table.columns.adjust().draw();
        }
        if (value1.html_id == reload) {
            console.log('works2');
            value1.table.ajax.reload(null, false);
        }
    });
}
```

The console looks like this everytime (being 324 the line outside the ifs)

```
scr_table2.js:324 scr-tablescr_tablescr_table1
scr_table2.js:324 scr-table1scr_tablescr_table1
scr_table2.js:324 scr-table2scr_tablescr_table1
scr_table2.js:324 scr-table3scr_tablescr_table1
```

Comment: When using `console.log`, you should do this: `console.log(value1.html_id, redraw, reload)`.  That way you can tell each of the 3 variables apart.

Comment: Looks like there's a mixup between `-` and `_` - `scr-table` and `scr_table`

Comment: Missing semicolon after the console.log?

Comment: I added the semicolon, no difference

Comment: I would recommend you use the [Chrome JavaScript debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) over `console.log()`. Most browsers have an equivalent if you don't use Chrome.

Comment: scr-table != scr_table != scr_table1

Comment: @SgtAJ Semicolons are not required in JavaScript, though many people (myself included) prefer them.

Comment: completely right, missed it, sorry

Comment: one tip for debugging is to also output the comparison, e.g.: `console.log(value1.html_id, redraw, value1.html_id === redraw)` (this will catch any failed assumptions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a typo, but `"scr-table"` is not equal to `"scr_table"`.

They differ - the first has a `-` and the second an `_`

You should also use the `===` operator when comparing values for equality  in JavaScript. It doesn't try to coerce types so you get a true comparison of equality.

Comment: wow, after staring at it for a while one doesn't even see those mistakes anymore!

Comment: @Niels Please see my edit and consider using the `===` operator. I'm glad I could help you out! ;-)

Comment: This === differs from PHP? There I thought it means that Even the types must match

Comment: Yes - `===` enforces that the types must also match. In 99% of cases this is desirable behaviour and can help catch nasty-to-find errors before they happen. Tools like [jshint](http://jshint.com/) can point out things like this for you aswell.